# Is there any way to disable table.poll.interval.ms for Kafka Connect Job?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

[Apache Kafka Connectors Config](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/configuration_options.html) parameter **table.poll.interval.ms** is Frequency in ms to poll for new or removed tables, which may result in updated task configurations to start polling for data in added tables or stop polling for data in removed tables. (Which we dont need.)

We don't want to execute such a query. Is there any way to disable this property?
Setting big interval value is a solution too. But no need to execute query.

```
SELECT
NULL AS table_cat,
o.owner AS table_schem,
o.object_name AS table_name,
o.object_type AS table_type,
NULL AS remarks FROM
all_objects o  WHERE
o.owner LIKE :1 ESCAPE '/'
AND o.object_name LIKE :2 ESCAPE '/'
AND o.object_type IN ('TABLE',
'SYNONYM',
'VIEW') ORDER BY
table_type,
table_schem,
table_name
```

Comment: Try setting to -1, although is this the query you've manually entered? Can you not remove `all_objects` from the table whitelist property?

Comment: @cricket_007Do you know for a fact if setting to -1 disables the polling ? or, is this a shot in the dark ?

Comment: Hi @SanjayDas When you set this value to -1, the query runs continuously.